# If I want to use UTF-8 encoding, the default for python, do I have to encode my string variables to byte variables?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, byte, file-writing

If I have a string that I want to use in byte form encoded as UTF-8, do I need to encode the variable as a byte variable? Or, since Python is by default encoded as UTF-8, will it just treat the string as UTF-8 byte form in certain contexts without explicit encoding?

For example, I'm working on a project where I have an array of dictionaries that map strings to strings. If I write this array to a file with json.dump and then read it with json.load, the strings are recovered just fine, and I get no error, despite never encoding. This indicates to me that if you're just using UTF-8, you don't actually need to convert to byte form. Am I wrong? If I'm right, is this bad practice nonetheless? Would my example be any different if I were just writing strings without the JSON?

Comment: I find difficult to understand. UTF-8 is just an encoding. Please use it just for input and output (if possible). All intern handling of string should be normally be done at decoded level, so in Python, as Unicode. It is a really good code practice to reduce the part of code where you have the encoded strings (byte strings), so try just to uses encoding just in input and output, at nearly first and last step, better without exposing byte strings to other function. So you do no need to worry about encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has multiple defaults regarding encoding.
In Python 3, the situation is as follows:

- The source file encoding is UTF-8 by default. You can override this with a comment in one of the first two lines of the module (`# coding: latin-1`) if you really have to. It only affects string literals (and variable names).
- The `encoding` parameter of `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()` is UTF-8 too.
- But when you open a file with `open()`, then the default for `encoding` depends on the circumstances (OS, env variables, Python version, build). You can check its value with `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. This default is also used when you read from `sys.stdin` or use `print()`.

So I'd say it's okay to rely on the defaults for the first two cases (it's officially recommended for the first one).
But the third one is tricky: The IO default is UTF-8 on many systems, so you might *think* that `with open(path) as f:` will always use UTF-8, because it did so during development, but then you port the script to a different server and suddenly it raises UnicodeErrors or produces gibberish.

It's often not necessary to deal with encoded strings (ie. `bytes` objects) for processing text.
Rather, you make sure to have it decoded when reading and encoded when writing/sending the text.
This is done automatically for streams created with `open()` (unless you specify binary mode `'rb'`/`'wb'`).
If you think input/output has to be UTF-8, then you should explicitly specify `encoding='utf8'` when calling `open()`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful; I guess I should encode just to be safe writing. I was just a little confused at the end. You write that encoding/decoding "is done automatically for streams created with open()." Wouldn't this imply that you don't need to use str.encode() and str.decode() before writing/reading if open() does it automatically? And also, what's the difference between using "encoding='utf8' when calling open()" and encoding the string to utf-8 with bytes before calling open to write it?

Comment: Exactly. If you open a text stream with `open(path, 'w', encoding='utf8')`, it will only accept `str` objects in the `write()` method. If you pass it `bytes` objects, eg. by converting through `str.encode()`, it will raise a TypeError.

Comment: Also: there is no `str.decode()`. It wouldn't make much sense; `str` objects are already decoded.